# How do you install Hyper V on Azure Dev Ops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to install Hyper V for an Azure Dev Ops (ADO) pipeline (using powershell task). When I do a "Get-VM", I am getting the typical powershell error "... not recognized as the name cmdlet" error so it make me believe Hyper V is not installed.  When I do a "Get-Module -listavailable" Hyper V is not listed.

I have a build agent with Windows 2019 and Windows 2022 and neither seems to work.

I have tried the following;

1. DISM /Online /NoRestart /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V /LogLevel:4    <-- seems to work but at the end of the task it just says Exit 1
2. Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -NoRestart -All

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline -NoRestart

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online -NoRestart

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients -NoRestart

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell -NoRestart -All

3. import-module Hyper-V   <-- says can't find module

I am stuck on what to do. I need Hyper V as part of my pipeline tests.

Thanks
Darren

Comment: Are you trying to install Hyper V on Microsoft hosted or Self hosted agents?

Comment: Microsoft hosted. I believe if it was self hosted, I could manually install it and have it all up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that Hyper V can't be enabled on Microsoft Hosted Agents. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations)

> Microsoft-hosted agents:
>
> - Run on Microsoft Azure general purpose virtual machines Standard_DS2_v2

Hyper V can only be enabled on Virtual Machines which supports Nested Virtualization. Check this link for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Unfortunately, [DSv2-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series#dsv2-series) do not support Nested Virtualization

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out somewhat.  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All  is sufficient to do it BUT a reboot is needed which is a new issue. Will follow up with that in a separate posting.

Comment: If you’re able to figure that out, you should [edit] this answer to include those details.